# How can I Add module as dependency Injection to a other throw code in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scripting

I need to make (Browse)button when click on it choose JS file from my computer (this file has module that I need to inject it ti Main module) I need to inject it to my Main Module.by code how can I do that?

Comment: That's a very interesting requirement. What is the use case ? And why do you want to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this before your angular application bootstrap.

So you need to write code that handles button click and fetches javascript file by adding script tag to your markup.

After that you need to manually bootstrap your angular application, using

```
angular.bootstrap('#root_element_id', ['RootModuleName']);
```

Of course, you cannot do button click handling using your angular application as it would not be bootstrapped yet.